# json_decode issues with \u characters

Tags: php, json, unicode, utf-8

I am trying to decode a json that I receive from the Eventbrite API which contains characters like these:

```
"The Zone Sports\u00a0\nWE TEACH AND BUILD LIFE SKILLS\nOur programs helps build your child\u2019s self-esteem, self-discipline,Work ethic and teamwork skills they\u2019ll need to succeed in life."
```

After using json_decode on this string I get the following text:

```
"The Zone SportsÂ WE TEACH AND BUILD LIFE SKILLS Our programs helps build your childâ€™s self-esteem, self-discipline,Work ethic and teamwork skills theyâ€™ll need to succeed in life."
```

The following thing should be displayed in the end:

```
The Zone Sports WE TEACH AND BUILD LIFE SKILLS Our programs helps build your child’s self-esteem, self-discipline,Work ethic and teamwork skills they’ll need to succeed in life.
```

This data is then written to an SQL database and then sent via an API to both Mobile APPs and a Website.
I am not 100% sure if this is the correct way to handle this, but what I am attempting is to write the \u characters directly into the database, so when read they are still in the correct format.
The whole problem happens on json_decode.
If I var_dump the text before decoding it looks ok, after decoding it's messed up.
Is there any option I need to add to the json_decode function or perhaps do some changes on the string beforehand?

Comment: How are you viewing the string?  It seems to work fine: https://3v4l.org/LPsRU, so my guess is you aren't supporting utf8 where you're viewing it.

Comment: @Devon is right.  Looks like `decode` is doing the right thing, returning a UTF8 encoded string ... but you are viewing it as LATIN1.  Unicode \u00a0 (non-breaking space) is encoded in UTF8 as hex c2a0.  c2, when viewed in Latin1/Ext-ASCII is an uppercase-A with circumflex (hat) and a0 is a space -- exactly what you're seeing.  Are you using MS Notepad on Windows?

Comment: @BareNakedCoder I am doing a var_dump in the PHP script and also the same thing can be seen when decoding using utf8 on an iPhone device and on a Laravel server that connects to the API and holds the front-end.
So you are saying that in the database the characters shouldn't be seen as \u but rather those strange symbols?
I am using HeidiSQL to look at the rows in the database